# Distinct count mismatch

Tags: sql, teradata

This is my initial table structure.

```
MEMBER_ID   ITEM_ID  ACCOUNT
 1           3        A
 1           4        A
 2           1        B
 3           4        B
 4           4        B
 5           4        A
 6           2        A
```

When I want the distinct number of members I do

```
Select COUNT(DISTINCT MEMBER_ID) FROM TABLE A
```

I get 6, the expected answer

When I do

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT MEMBER_ID),ACCOUNT FROM TABLE A GROUP BY 2
```

I get something like A=4 and B=3, what do you think is the disconnect here.

Thanks

Comment: What if you do `SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT MEMBER_ID), ACCOUNT FROM TABLE A GROUP BY ACCOUNT` instead?

Comment: This seems highly unlikely.  Unfortunately, SQL Fiddle doesn't support teradata.

Comment: Same kinda result when I replace column number by column name.

Comment: Works as expected for me (for the data you showed). If you actually get A=4 for this data it would be a bug, otherwise see Gordon's answer.

Answer (score 0):

I find the results highly unlikely.  You would, however, get 4 and 3 if the data were slightly different:

```
MEMBER_ID   ITEM_ID  ACCOUNT
 1           3        A
 1           4        B
 2           1        B
 3           4        B
 4           4        A
 5           4        A
 6           2        A
```

With the `group by`, `MEMBER_ID = 1` would be counted twice -- once for A and once for B.  My guess is that something like this is happening for your real problem.  `COUNT(DISTINCT)` is *not* additive.  So, when you break it in apart using a `group by`, the sum of the values is not (necessarily) the sum for all the data.  This differs from `MIN()`, `MAX()`, `COUNT(*)`, and `SUM()`.  However, `AVG()` is also not additive (although it is easily recalculated).

Comment: Then how do we get the split up of members without using DISTINCT.